# Is MySql doing a sequential search if the SELECT contains a WHERE clause that searches a huge list

Tags: mysql

Table A has an index on 'ObjectId'. We are querying this table using a select similar to this:

```
SELECT FROM `A` AS a where  `a`.`objectId` IN 
('00017a41-1ac0-4775-822b-de00cfd5902d', '000216dc-03cb-4e73-8177-3c2e49bc6622', '00035b33-2a62-464a-817b-6e23e8961bce')
```

In this case a list of three objectids.

But in our real world this list can be over 30.000 items. And in our mysql.slow_log we see something like this:

[image]

almost 9.000.000 records examined and almost 32.000 records found. Now if it was using the ObjectId index, I would assume it would not examine so many records. That many sounds to me like a sequential search.

I tried testing this in MySql workbench and using 'explain' with a smaller number in the list, it tells me it will use the objectid-index

[image]

I cannot query or explain this with a list of 32.000 items, then Workbench crashes. So what is going on, is there a limit on the number in which it will do an indexed search and when it exceeds that number it will do a sequential search? Or is the examined records in the log not what I think it is?

Comment: If you run explain select . .. you see your email bdec issn`t used. ,ou can write a union with three selemcs or use inner join

Comment: Instead of querying with a huge IN list, consider breaking the query into smaller chunks. For instance, if you have 30,000 IDs, you might run 30 queries with 1,000 IDs each. This can sometimes be more efficient and might encourage better use of indexes. There might be inherent limitations in the MySQL query optimizer, especially with older versions of MySQL. Upgrading to a newer version might yield better optimization for such queries.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table containing all the values in the `IN` list, then join with that table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_items (
    objectid CHAR(36)
);
INSERT INTO temp_items (objectid) VALUES ('00017a41-1ac0-4775-822b-de00cfd5902d'), ('000216dc-03cb-4e73-8177-3c2e49bc6622'), ('00035b33-2a62-464a-817b-6e23e8961bce');
ALTER TABLE temp_items ADD INDEX (objectid);

SELECT a.*
FROM a 
JOIN temp_items USING (objectid);
```

This will use the index in `temp_items` instead of a sequential search. If `a.objectid` is also indexed, this will be as efficient as MySQL is capable.

Answer (score 1):

@TSAmerica.com
You were right dividing it in smaller chunks solved the problem.
Testing showed that when the list is over ~13.000 items, the search became sequential. So we now chop the search in chunks of 10.000.